# Special linear group is a simple algebraic group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

I am looking for a reference for the proof that the special linear group over an algebraically closed field is a simple algebraic group, i.e., a connected algebraic group that has no proper normal connected subgroups. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here is a sketch](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group_is_simple#Proof) of such a proof

Comment: @avs I think I might be missing the argument for connectedness. Indeed,  any group maps to the trivial group and is therefore the inverse image of a connected set.

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Comment: Under certain conditions, $SL_n(K)$ is only quasisimple; yet its quotient  $PSL_n(K)$ is simple.